# Ubuntu 20.04 auto connect bluetooth sound devices

Tags: 20.04, sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 on a Lenovo Flex 14.  I have several bluetooth sound devices.  All connect and play.  However I must connect them manually each time despite all being trusted devices.  Then I have to go to PAVU to shut off the laptop speaker and any external monitor sound.  Is there some way to have these devices connect automatically?

Comment: Ubuntu 20?  So this is a Ubuntu Core 20 install  (the *year* format products are different to the far more widely used *year.month* products of Ubuntu).  Please clarify or confirm  (the 20 or *year* products are less powerful than the 20.04 or *year.month* products, having other advantages though)

Comment: Not only connect automatically but also be selected automatically as the device to which sound is to be routed.

Comment: I am using 20.04 with all the latest updates

Comment: Please correct your question then, 20.04 can use `apt` commands & *deb* packages, where as 20 cannot. They are different products, the *year* format being reserved for *snap* only products of Ubuntu since 2016; details matter so please don't provide incorrect or invalid details.  Ubuntu Core 20 is a server system that cannot run Ubuntu Desktop (it's only available via *deb* package)